# Python thread doesn't change global variable inside a function

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

The most basic form of something I want to code is the code as follows:

```
import threading

arr = []
def test(id):
    global arr
    arr.append(id)

threading.Thread(target=test, args="8")
print(arr)
```

What I want to do is to append "8" to a global variable called *arr* But this doesn't happen, and *print(arr)* gives this output:

```
[]
```

However, if I use this code, everything works fine:

```
import threading

arr = []
def test(id):
    global arr
    arr.append(id)

test("8")
print(arr)
```

The problem seems to be with thread, so how can I use thread and also change the value of a global variable inside the function *test*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to start the thread to actually run the function `test`

```
import threading

arr = []
def test(id):
    global arr
    arr.append(id)

t = threading.Thread(target=test, args="8")
t.start()
t.join()
print(arr)
```